# Exclude directories from pathname expansion results

Tags: bash, loops

I have 100 directories and need to move the ones *not* in a certain list into a single new directory.

I am trying variations of:

```
for A in !(sub-9002 sub-9003 sub-9004 sub-9005 sub-9008 sub-9009 sub-9011 sub-9014 sub-9018 sub-9020 sub-9023 sub-9025 sub-9026 sub-9028 sub-9029 sub-9033 sub-9034 sub-9036 sub-9038 sub-9039 sub-9040 sub-9041 sub-9042 sub-9045 sub-9046 sub-9047 sub-9048 sub-9049 sub-9055 sub-9058 sub-9061 sub-9062 sub-9064 sub-9065 sub-9068 sub-9069 sub-9071 sub-9072 sub-9079 sub-9080 sub-9081 sub-9084 sub-9085 sub-9086 sub-9087 sub-9088 sub-9089 sub-9092 sub-9093 sub-9094 sub-9096 sub-9098 sub-9100);
do 
   mv -f $A Bad/;
done
```

I'm also trying:

```
if [[! A in (sub-9002 sub-9003 sub-9004 sub-9005 sub-9008 sub-9009 sub-9011 sub-9014 sub-9018 sub-9020 sub-9023 sub-9025 sub-9026 sub-9028 sub-9029 sub-9033 sub-9034 sub-9036 sub-9038 sub-9039 sub-9040 sub-9041 sub-9042 sub-9045 sub-9046 sub-9047 sub-9048 sub-9049 sub-9055 sub-9058 sub-9061 sub-9062 sub-9064 sub-9065 sub-9068 sub-9069 sub-9071 sub-9072 sub-9079 sub-9080 sub-9081 sub-9084 sub-9085 sub-9086 sub-9087 sub-9088 sub-9089 sub-9092 sub-9093 sub-9094 sub-9096 sub-9098 sub-9100)]]; then 
    mv -f $A Bad/;
fi
```

Comment: What's the actual issue? Any error messages? Any files not being moved? Also, [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative-match extended glob pattern, but you need to do `set -s extglob` first, and then the pattern syntax is `!(sub-9002|sub-9003|sub-9004|...)`. I'd also recommend using lower- or mixed-case variable names (there are a bunch of all-caps names with special meanings, and you don't want to accidentally use one of those), and also double-quote variable references (e.g. `"$a"` instead of just `$a`) to avoid weird parsing problems. Oh, and you don't need a semicolon at the end of lines.

```
shopt -s extglob
for a in !(sub-9002|sub-9003|sub-9004|sub-9005|sub-9008|sub-9009|sub-9011|sub-9014|sub-9018|sub-9020|sub-9023|sub-9025|sub-9026|sub-9028|sub-9029|sub-9033|sub-9034|sub-9036|sub-9038|sub-9039|sub-9040|sub-9041|sub-9042|sub-9045|sub-9046|sub-9047|sub-9048|sub-9049|sub-9055|sub-9058|sub-9061|sub-9062|sub-9064|sub-9065|sub-9068|sub-9069|sub-9071|sub-9072|sub-9079|sub-9080|sub-9081|sub-9084|sub-9085|sub-9086|sub-9087|sub-9088|sub-9089|sub-9092|sub-9093|sub-9094|sub-9096|sub-9098|sub-9100);
do 
   mv -f "$a" Bad/
done
```

BTW, `[[ ]]` conditional expressions don't have anything like an `in` operator. But they do require spaces after the `[[` and before the `]]`.